# Get results and fade

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Don't know what is wrong, I've tried everything. The code should take simple info from PHP file and for each should fade in delay and out. I was successful with getting all the data at once but it is not good.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('button').fadeOut('slow')
    var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
    var percentVal = 0;
    window.setInterval(function(){
        percentVal += 10;
        progressBar.css("width", percentVal+ '%').attr("aria-valuenow", percentVal+ '%').text(percentVal+ '%');
        if (percentVal == 100)
        {
            percentVal = 0;
        }
    }, 500);

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").click(function() {                

            $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                type: "GET",
                url: "submit.php",
                data: 'html',   //expect html to be returned                
                success: function(data){ 
                    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
                        $('.input-group').html(data).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
                    }

                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

PHP CODE:

```
$array= ['apple','orange','grapes','avocado','banana'];
$indexedOnly = array();

foreach ($array as $row) {
    $indexedOnly[] = array_values($row);
}

echo json_encode($indexedOnly);
```

Comment: Did you get any error in console?

Comment: array_values($row); this function needs an array and you are passing string value

Comment: based on what you code is like all your elements are applied in the same time. So you should see `banana` being the only one faded... as you are changing the content of the same element

Comment: yes just [null,null,null,null,null] but i see it take all the data at once :( i am confused

Comment: i remove array values now is just fade in and out 6 this ['apple','orange','grapes','avocado','banana']

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you want to achieve. Is it fade in stay for 1sec then fade out... and repeat that for all the words?

Comment: i want to retrive the data one by one and fade in then fade out, but when i was succeful it just take all the data at once the fade it . the timing it was just for test

Comment: i read something about .each but i cant use it succeful

Comment: As I said, `for(var i=0;i<6;i++){` will loop 6 times and you're adding the entire `data` which is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to abandon the loops, they wont allow you to pause to wait for the animation to finish. You can try something like this where you handle each element in data then using the callback functions of `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` to call the next one

```
 function disp_next() {
 $('.input-group').text(data.shift()).hide();
    $('.input-group').fadeIn()
  .delay(1000)
  .fadeOut(function(){
    if(data.length !== 0) {
        disp_next();
    }
  })
 }

 disp_next();
```

You also need to change your `dataType` to `json` as you are expecting json from the server. Here is your jquery updated

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").click(function() {                

              $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                type: "GET",
                url: "submit.php",
                datatype: 'json',   //expect html to be returned                
                success: function(data){ 
                 data = Object.values(data);
                 function disp_next() {
                   $('.input-group').text(data.shift()).hide();
                    $('.input-group').fadeIn()
                    .delay(1000)
                    .fadeOut(function(){
                      if(data.length !== 0) {
                        disp_next();
                      }
                    })
                 }

                 disp_next();


            }
              });

       });
    });
```

Comment: thank you but how i use it i am new to jquery after succes ? thanks

Comment: it don't work i push the button and nothing happens :(

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? You may need to add `data = Object.values(data);` right above `function disp_next(){...`

Comment: @AdrianKlark sorry, i changed the answer, where it said fruits it should have been data

Comment: i put it my self it working the problem is it dont take the string just letter like this [ a b c d f and stops lol why is that ?

Comment: i need apple fade avocade fade banana fade etc

Comment: did you change your dataType to json?

Comment: mayby beacuse i use json ?

Comment: yes, you need to change your dataType in your ajax call to json, that way it expects json from the server. here is a fiddle I made https://jsfiddle.net/s340fzdd/

Comment: i change to data: 'json' but is the same :(

Comment: the problem is i take the data from php

Comment: No you need to set `dataType` not `data`. `data` is what you are sending to the server, `dataType` is what you expect from the server

Comment: like so data:"html"
                dataType:"json",  ?

Comment: You actually dont need the `data` attribute, that is not for GET requests like you are doing. but the dataType is correct. I edited my answer, try and put the updated jquery in your script and see if it works

Comment: Thanks it work i modify the php file and remove data thank for understanding !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, but if you want the animation of each element to wait for the previous one to finish you need to change the approach.

```
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
    $('.input-group').html(data).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: thanks, sorry for the stupid question but where should i put it after succes: ?

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking for, he wants to loop through one at a time, displaying each independently

Comment: just instead of you loop, but the response from @CumminUp07 might be what you're after.